# How can I move rows to other sheets onEdit and print a Time Stamp on a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a begginer in java script and I'm trying to do a bad-ass Montly finance sheet to operate through my cel phone. Hehe

I built a template for the first part of the process, where you can find here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbM78R7wYqKMwQOHJ6BA4M389c6dLZICRi75khqswO4/edit?usp=sharing

I have two Sheets in my Google sheets:

1 - INPUT

2 - EXPENSES

I wanna copy rows from INPUT and paste in EXPENSES as soon as I input OK on colunm E.

I already found a very good script here in the Forum that does that, by ScampMichael.

```
function onEdit(event) { //Script by ScampMichael https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0hR40qh02UWE/?hl=en
  // assumes source data in sheet named INPUT
  // target sheet of move to named EXPENSES
  // test column with yes/no is col 5 or E
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "INPUT" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "OK") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EXPENSES");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

It's working fine for my purposes. However, I wanna customize it and add extra functions to it, which are:

1 -  When it copies rows from INPUT and pastes in EXPENSES, it should always create a new row below the last row in EXPENSES and it should always leave one empty row in INPUT with the formatting and data validation boxes as this template comes with. Right now it's not what the script is doing. When it moves the data to expenses sheet, it deletes the original row from input and creates a blank new one without the formatting and data validation boxes.

2 - I would like the script to add a TIME STAMP in column D (date) in EXPENSES in case the same correspondent cell is empty from when it copies from INPUT. In other words, if I do not input the date of the expense, after it moves from input to expense, it shall add the date of the current day the row was copied.

Could anyone help me on this, please?

Thank you so much if you read this far. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try- I am sure there are better ways- But I think it does function...

```js
function onEdit(event) { //Script by ScampMichael https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0hR40qh02UWE/?hl=en
  // assumes source data in sheet named INPUT
  // target sheet of move to named EXPENSES
  // test column with yes/no is col 5 or E
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "INPUT" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == "OK") {
     var cellD2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D2');  
    if (cellD2.getValue() == 0 || cellD2.getValue() == "") {
    cellD2.setValue(new Date())
    }
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EXPENSES");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

    
  }
  setValidation();
}

function setValidation() {
     // Set the data validation for cell A2 to require a number greater than 0.
 var cellA2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2');
 var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireNumberGreaterThan(0).build();
 cellA2.setDataValidation(rule2);
  var cellB2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B2');
 var ruleB2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Pharmacy', 'Rent','Supermarket'], false).build();
 cellB2.setDataValidation(ruleB2);
   var cellC2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C2');
 var ruleC2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireNumberGreaterThan(0).build();
 cellC2.setDataValidation(ruleC2);
   var cellD2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D2');
 var ruleD2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireDate().build();
 cellD2.setDataValidation(ruleD2);
}
```